# Accessing a string by character as if it were an array

Tags: php, string

I have:

```
<?php    
$str = "Robert";
echo $str['e'];
?>
```

Outputs:

"R"

Why is this?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: Because `E` isn't numeric, so it is cast to `0`, which is the offset to the `first` character in `$str`, which is `R`

Comment: it looks like you want `strpos($str, 'e');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your code is returning "R" because the string 'e' has no numerical value, therefore it is 0. since it is 0, that means this is calling the string from the 0 location which is "R" for "Robert.

try using the String Position function like so:

```
strpos($str, 'e');
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because when you do this , you cast `e` to `integer`

```
echo (int)'e' returns  0.
```

That's like : `echo $str[0]` which returns **R**

Answer (score 2):

Basically, when you use `E`, it casts to zero, because it is expecting an integer. You could use it like this

```
strpos($str,"e");
```

Then, to verify that you have what you want, you would use

```
$str[strpos($str,"e")];
```